# PHP - curl ocr api request not returning anything (Curl error: No URL set!)

Tags: php, api, curl

I'm unable to retrieve any data from the api request, the php file simply displays the html fields but no data. I'm not receiving any response in the console either. Can someone please help with what is wrong, I've tried the api in python and it worked, so im guessing the issue isn't with the api.

```
<?php
$filename = 'https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/realistic-receipt-template_23-2147938550.jpg';
$cfile    = new CurlFile( $filename, 'image/jpeg', $filename );
$data     = array( 'file' => $cfile );

$taggun_endpoint = 'https://api.taggun.io/api/receipt/v1/simple/file';
$ch      = curl_init();
$options = array(
    CURLOPT_URL            => $taggun_endpoint,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT    => true,
    CURLOPT_HEADER         => true,
    CURLOPT_POST           => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER     => array(
        'apikey: 89ee3510883711eab7efc1191d38e165',
        'Accept: application/json',
        'Content-Type: multipart/form-data',
    ),
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => $data,
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.16 (KHTML, like Gecko) \ Chrome/24.0.1304.0 Safari/537.16'
);

curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );
$result      = curl_exec( $ch );
$header_info = curl_getinfo( $ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT );
$header_size = curl_getinfo( $ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE );
$header      = substr( $result, 0, $header_size );
$body        = substr( $result, $header_size );
curl_close( $ch );

echo $header_info;
echo $header;

?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>File Upload results</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Raw Result: <?php echo $result; ?>
    <p>Header Sent: <?php echo $header_info; ?></p>
    <p>Header Received: <?php echo $header; ?></p>
    <p>Body: <?php echo $body; ?></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: And what is the response or the result of curl_error? And, by the way, in their examples there’s no code with image file on another server, which makes me thinking that may be your issue.

Comment: The error produced is "No URL set!"

Comment: I'll give you the benefit of the doubt that the API key you've included in your post *isn't* your actual production API key, but if it is, I would recommend invalidating it **immediately** before (potentially malicious) third parties begin to use/abuse it.

Comment: Yes, its a demo key.

Comment: Daniel, I've tried with files stored locally. Same result.

Comment: Try curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true) to get more information about it (or add it to your array of options)